# Spark : writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to retrieve tweets from my Kafka cluster to Spark Streaming in which I perform some analysis to store them in an ElasticSearch Index.

Versions :
Spark - 2.3.0
Pyspark - 2.3.0
Kafka - 2.3.0
Elastic Search - 7.9
Elastic Search Hadoop - 7.6.2

I run the following code in my Jupyter env to write the streaming dataframe into Elastic Search .

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.3.0,org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop:7.6.2 pyspark-shell'

from pyspark import SparkContext
#    Spark Streaming
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
#    Kafka
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
#    json parsing
import json
import nltk
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

def getSqlContextInstance(sparkContext):
    if ('sqlContextSingletonInstance' not in globals()):
        globals()['sqlContextSingletonInstance'] = SQLContext(sparkContext)
    return globals()['sqlContextSingletonInstance']


def analyze_sentiment(tweet):

    scores = dict([('pos', 0), ('neu', 0), ('neg', 0), ('compound', 0)])
    sentiment_analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    score = sentiment_analyzer.polarity_scores(tweet)
    for k in sorted(score):
        scores[k] += score[k]

    return json.dumps(scores)

def process(time,rdd):
    
     print("========= %s =========" % str(time))
     
     try:
        if rdd.count()==0: 
            raise Exception('Empty')
            
        sqlContext = getSqlContextInstance(rdd.context)
        
        df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
        df = df.filter("text not like 'RT @%'")
        
        if df.count() == 0: 
            raise Exception('Empty')
            
        udf_func = udf(lambda x: analyze_sentiment(x),returnType=StringType())
        df = df.withColumn("Sentiment",lit(udf_func(df.text)))
        print(df.take(10))
        
        
        df.writeStream.outputMode('append').format('org.elasticsearch.spark.sql').option('es.nodes','localhost').option('es.port',9200)\
        .option('checkpointLocation','/checkpoint').option('es.spark.sql.streaming.sink.log.enabled',False).start('PythonSparkStreamingKafka_RM_01').awaitTermination()
        
        
     except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSparkStreamingKafka_RM_01")
sc.setLogLevel("INFO")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 20)

kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ['kafkaspark'], {
                        'bootstrap.servers':'localhost:9092', 
                        'group.id':'spark-streaming', 
                        'fetch.message.max.bytes':'15728640',
                        'auto.offset.reset':'largest'})

parsed = kafkaStream.map(lambda v: json.loads(v[1]))

parsed.foreachRDD(process)

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination(timeout=180)
```

But I get the error :

```
'writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;
```

And , it looks like I have to use .readStream , but how do I use it to read from KafkaStream without CreateDirectStream ?

Could someone please help me with writing this dataframe into Elastic Search . I am a beginner to Spark Streaming and Elastic Search and find it quite challenging . Would be happy if someone could guide me through getting this done.

Comment: You can use `.write` since you have a non-Streaming Dataframe, but I also don't see anything preventing you from converting those operations into a structured streaming. Note: you could also use `faust` and Kafka Connect Elasticsearch sink and skip Spark/Hadoop environment completely

Comment: I tried .write() but it gave me an error saying 'index already exists' and couldn't append to ES.

Comment: Sounds like an elasticsearch error, but it at least solved the Spark error

Answer (score 2):

`.writeStream` is a part of the [Spark Structured Streaming API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html), so you need to use corresponding API to start reading the data - the [`spark.readStream`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#creating-streaming-dataframes-and-streaming-datasets), and pass options specific for the Kafka source that are described in the [separate document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html), and also use the additional jar that contains the Kafka implementation.   The corresponding code would look like that ([full code is here](https://github.com/alexott/cassandra-dse-playground/blob/master/spark-dse/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/streaming/StructuredStreamingKafkaDSE.scala)):

```scala
   val streamingInputDF = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.10:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "tweets-txt")
      .load()
```

Comment: Thanks ! But , I get the error 'name 'spark' does not exist' . I tried resolving it , but it gives rise to many other errors.

Comment: Do you have any idea what to do about that ?

Comment: you need to init it with `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()`

Comment: "
An error occurred while calling o84.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka

"

Thanks . I resolved the spark error . But , I'm getting the above issue on running your code. My class path :


" '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.3.0,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-8_2.11-2.3.0,org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop:7.6.2 pyspark-shell'  "

Could you please help me out ?

Comment: Changed the class path to :
"'--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0,org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-hadoop:7.6.2 pyspark-shell' ".

But sadly , I still get the same " Failed to find data source:kafka".